Fragment navigation issue in addToBackStack
In Activity oncreate
// oncreate
FragmentHealthReadingKt readingFragment;
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "#2 reading Fragment created !!! ");
                    readingFragment = FragmentHealthReadingKt.newInstance(patientId);
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.content_frame, readingFragment,"FragmentHealthReadingKt")
                            .addToBackStack("FragmentHealthReadingKt") // Add this line to add the transaction to the back stack
                            .commit();

//
SlideMenuClickListener
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // to avoid multiple click on same item
            if (position == selectedItem && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                return;
            }

            final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (position != 1) {
                selectedItem = position;
                setActionBarTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);

            } else {
                picked_device_id = 0;
                               try {
                    CommunicationManager.getInstance().shutDownCommunication();
                } catch (UCHApiConfigException e) {
                    // TODO, ignore this error.
                }
            }

            CommonUtils.enableMessageNotificationFlags(getApplicationContext());

            patientId = (patientId == 0) ? AppPref.getPrefInt(getApplicationContext(), AppPref.USER_REMOTE_ID)
                    : patientId;

            AppPref.updatePref(getApplicationContext(), "UI", -1);

          

            // fragmentManager.popBackStack();

            switch (adapter.getaction(position)) {

                case 1:
                    isResultFlag = true;
//                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                            .replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentHealthReadingKt.newInstance(patientId))
//                            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    FragmentHealthReadingKt healthReadingFragment = (FragmentHealthReadingKt) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentHealthReadingKt");

                    if (healthReadingFragment == null) {
                        Log.e("bbbbbvv","yes");
                        // If FragmentHealthReadingKt is not added, create and add it
                        healthReadingFragment = FragmentHealthReadingKt.newInstance(patientId);
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.content_frame, healthReadingFragment, "FragmentHealthReadingKt")
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("bbbbbvv","nooooooo");
                        // If FragmentHealthReadingKt is already added, just show it
                                             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .show(healthReadingFragment) // Ensure the fragment is shown
                                .commit();
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:

                    isResultFlagnotify = true;
                    // Log.e("notifi_idz",""+notifi_id);
                        Log.e("notifi_idz","FragmentNotesList");
                        FragmentNotesList noteFragment;
                        Logger.debug(TAG, "#1 reading Fragment created for picked device id kkkk " + picked_device_id);
                        noteFragment = FragmentNotesList.newInstance(patientId);
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, noteFragment).commit();
                

//                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, FragmentNotesList.newInstance(patientId))
//                            .commit();
                    break;

    

                default:
                    break;
            }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

//Here first I call FragmentHealthReadingKt next I choose FragmentNotesList. functionality we need first time only load FragmentHealthReadingKt next we go to any fragment  next click
FragmentHealthReadingKt no need to reload FragmentHealthReadingKt. just popup that fragment.
now this condition not working. anyone help me what problem here
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .show(healthReadingFragment) // Ensure the fragment is shown
                                .commit(); 

